# retrieve current path from file saved on server

Tags: vba, ms-access

How I can retrieve the current path of current db?
I've one AC07 program, to distribute it I save one copy on the intranet server, how to copy  this program into our PC and then use it?
Always some people open the file directly on server.

When the file is open one form star automatically, in this form I put this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim StrServer As String
StrServer = "\\itbgafs01\Comune\Dashboard\"
If GetDBPath() = StrServer Then
    MsgBox "You can't open this file from server" & vbCrLf & _
            "save one copy on you PC, and use those", vbCritical, "Dashboard.info"
    Application.Quit
End If
Public Function GetDBPath() As String
    Dim strFullPath As String
    Dim I As Integer

    strFullPath = CurrentDb().Name

    For I = Len(strFullPath) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(strFullPath, I, 1) = "\" Then
            GetDBPath = left(strFullPath, I)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

My problem is: some PC are mapped on drive H: the server directory then the path result is `H:\Comune\Dashboard\` and not `\\itbgafs01\\Dashboard\`.
How I can retrieve the absolute path?
First I think to use more if like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim StrServer As String
Dim StrMaph As String
StrServer = "\\itbgafs01\Comune\Dashboard\"
StrMaph = "H:\Comune\Dashboard\"
MsgBox StrServer & vbCrLf & _
        StrMaph & vbCrLf & _
        GetDBPath()
If GetDBPath() = StrServer Or GetDBPath() = StrMaph Then
    MsgBox "Non puoi aprire il file sul server" & vbCrLf & _
            "copialo sul tuo pC ed avvia il programma da li", vbCritical, "Dashboard.info"
    Application.Quit
End If
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can use an API call to retrieve the server of the mapped drive. But your current method with the dual check is clean an simple, so why not stick to it?

Comment: @Gustav, yes the method with the dual choice is good, but some you know into a company with more 1000 user is easy that someone maph the server directory on S: or Z: or X: ...... my is overzealous (translate from google, this word exist really in english??)Thank

Comment: OK, you named only drive H. Then you should an API method - like the one provided by Cor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Scripting Runtime to get the UNC path of the drive then replace it in the currentDb.Name.

E.g.:

```
Sub blah()
    Debug.Print GetUNCPath(CurrentDb.Name)
End Sub


Function GetUNCPath(path As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object, shareName
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    shareName = fso.GetDrive( _
                            fso.GetDriveName(path)).shareName

    'sharename is empty if it wasn't a network mapped drive (e.g. local C: drive)
    If shareName <> "" Then
        GetUNCPath = shareName & Right(path, Len(path) - InStr(1, path, "\"))
    Else
        GetUNCPath = path
    End If

End Function
```

Edit: alternatively you can use a call to the WinAPI to get the info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/160529

Comment: @Fabrizio thanks - glad it helped. Please mark this as the answer for other people's future reference.